# iptables are not forwarding any traffic to HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, iptables, portforwarding

I've got the following problem:

My Router (FritzBox) is set to forward all incomming traffic (via exposed host) to my Server (192.168.0.1)

I have a HAProxy running on a lxc container (192.168.0.100) which is forwarding http traffic to some other lxc containers - this is working fine.

The problem is, when I run the following command (curl to my proxy) I get the right answer back:

```
curl --verbose --header 'Host: myrealdomain.tld' http://192.168.0.100


* Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.0.100/
*   Trying 192.168.0.100...
* Connected to 192.168.0.100 (192.168.0.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: murdr.eu
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>

* Closing connection 0
```

But when running the same command (curl to my server which should forward the traffic to the Proxy) I can't connect, because the connection is refused:

```
curl --verbose --header 'Host: myrealdomain.tld' http://192.168.0.1


* Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.0.1/
*   Trying 192.168.0.1...
* connect to 192.168.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 192.168.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

(myrealdomain.tld is replaced with my real domain, here I changed it for security reasons)

Here are my iptables (I've tested various things and flushed then often, but nothing was working).

- I've cleared them now, better start fresh

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

iptables -L -t nat

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

iptables -S (as asked by Luke Mlsna)

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

apache2 was running on my server. but I deleted it after setting up the proxy container and the iptables.

here are the open ports, no port 80

```
lsof -i -P -n


COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-n  938 systemd-network   19u  IPv6  33240      0t0  UDP [fe80::f64d:30ff:fe66:8010]:546
systemd-r  980 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4  22967      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.53:53
systemd-r  980 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  22968      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
nmbd      1108            root   15u  IPv4  22474      0t0  UDP *:137
nmbd      1108            root   16u  IPv4  22475      0t0  UDP *:138
nmbd      1108            root   17u  IPv4  38559      0t0  UDP 192.168.0.1:137
nmbd      1108            root   18u  IPv4  38560      0t0  UDP 192.168.1.255:137
nmbd      1108            root   19u  IPv4  38561      0t0  UDP 192.168.0.1:138
nmbd      1108            root   20u  IPv4  38562      0t0  UDP 192.168.1.255:138
sshd      1200            root    3u  IPv4  25135      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1200            root    4u  IPv6  25137      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
lxd       1273            root   13u  IPv6  27850      0t0  TCP *:8443 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1501           mysql   39u  IPv4  27943      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
smbd      3606            root   32u  IPv6  37803      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
smbd      3606            root   33u  IPv6  37804      0t0  TCP *:139 (LISTEN)
smbd      3606            root   34u  IPv4  37805      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
smbd      3606            root   35u  IPv4  37806      0t0  TCP *:139 (LISTEN)
sshd      6140            root    3u  IPv4  59450      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.1:22->192.168.0.43:62339 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd      6350         unicorn    3u  IPv4  59450      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.1:22->192.168.0.43:62339 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: Do `iptables -S` or `iptables-save`, I can't read this format for crap. This looks like just blank rules..?

Comment: Also, do you have `ipv4.ip_forward=1`set in `/etc/sysctl.conf` ?

Comment: I've added what you asked to my question, yes, they are now blank rules, because nothing was working (better start fresh)

Comment: and yes, ipv4_forward is set to 1

Comment: What machine are you trying to run curl from? And what are you expecting to see on port 80 of your proxy?

Comment: 503 = "You are asking HAproxy to proxy for something that isnt there" it was probably proxying for apache2 which is now gone. So it IS hitting the proxy, but has nowhere to go after that.

Comment: I've run this on ubuntu (on windows) and mac. I expect seeing the same result when I curl to 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.0.1, because 192.168.0.1 should forward everything on port 80 to 192.168.0.100

Comment: 503 = I know, that is right, the proxy is sending everything to another lxc container, which is not running any webserver yet - but that's something I expected. The problem is just the not working forwarding on port 80 from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.100

Comment: I mean, from what IP address are you running curl from to try to hit 192.168.0.100?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174559/discussion-between-luke-mlsna-and-fachinformatiker).

Comment: I‘m back home, see ya in chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sending my traffic now directly to HAProxy from my router, no server in between.
Working as a charm!